# github project pages Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/htm

Tags: javascript, angularjs, github, github-pages

Fore some reason I can not get my Github project page to load my javascripts. I am getting the following in console:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://siddhion.github.io/scripts/cdf6190d.scripts.js".
siddhion.github.io/:109 
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://siddhion.github.io/scripts/angular.min.js".
angular.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
cdf6190d.scripts.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
cdf6190d.scripts.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Here is my Github project page

http://siddhion.github.io/maxmythic/

and my gh-page repo

https://github.com/siddhion/maxmythic/tree/gh-pages

Any ideas what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing your project name in the URL you are using for your scripts.
The URL format for gh-pages is:

http://{ownername (user or organization)}.github.io/{project_name}

Thus your javascript file can be accessed by the following URL
[http://siddhion.github.io/**maxmythic**/scripts/cdf6190d.scripts.js](http://siddhion.github.io/maxmythic/scripts/cdf6190d.scripts.js)

Comment: And it comes with the correct mime type application/javascript

Answer (score 0):

You're expecting JavaScript code as a response from

```
/scripts/cdf6190d.scripts.js
/scripts/angular.min.js
```

But instead you're getting a 404 html webpage.

[image]